# Delay in DirectoryEntry Refreshcache

Tags: .net, performance, delay, directoryentry

We are finding a significant delay (11 or more seconds depending on environment and load) when calling .NET's System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache(). This delay is due to generic attempts to lookup the DC name via DNS and WINS. Does anyone know how to direct .NET to use the server name provided? Details are provided in sections below.

DNS Lookup:
.NET goes through a series of DNS queries for the service, using the server name in the query. This query doesn't work, of course. .NET then fails over to WINS/NetBIOS to find the server name. That does not work so .NET fails over to querying the DNS system for an A record using the server name. That final step works. There are significant delays in some of these steps.

Frequency:
If test iterations are spaced well enough apart, this problem occurs at the beginning of each test iteration. Under more intense test loads, the problem may skip a test iteration or two.

Subsequent connection attempts within each test iteration typically perform well (I don't know why multiple connections are made per iteration - an issue for another day).

Tech:
The client computer that hosts the code is a member of a different domain than the Active Directory server. Trusts have been established between domains.

Code:

```
AuthenticationTypes authTypes = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
String connect = "LDAP://servername.otherdomain:636/DC=otherdomain"
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(connect, serviceAccount, PWD, authTypes)
de.RefreshCache(); // The delay is specific to this line.

// And so on...
dtree = de.Children;
policy = new DomainPolicy(de);
...
```

Thanks

Comment: DNS lookup does not seem to be the issue. Added the DC to the server's host file with no change in performance.

Comment: Looks like .NET goes through a series of DNS lookups for the service, using the server name in the query. This query doesn't work, of course so .NET fails over to WINS/NetBIOS to find the server name. That does not work so .NET fails over to querying the DNS system for an A record using the server name. That final step works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to change the line

AuthenticationTypes authTypes = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;

with

AuthenticationTypes authTypes = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer || AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;

By specifying "ServerBind" we let the application know that the connection string contains a server name.

Without this ServerBind value, the components involved begin a guessing game beginning with an attempt to query DNS for a service name that contains the string given, then fails over to WINS and then again to DNS for an A record using the server name. All of these actions cost a significant amount of time.